# Ruby's attr_accessor magic method defining

Tags: ruby

For a better understanding of Ruby I decided to recreate the attr_accessor method. Succesfully. I now understand how it works except for one detail regarding Ruby's syntactic sugar. Here's the attr_accessor method I created:

```
def attr_accessor(*attributes)
  attributes.each do |a|
    # Create a setter method (obj.name=)
    setter = Proc.new do |val|
      instance_variable_set("@#{a}", val)
    end

    # Create a getter method (obj.name)
    getter = Proc.new do
      instance_variable_get("@#{a}")
    end

    self.class.send(:define_method, "#{a}=", setter)
    self.class.send(:define_method, "#{a}", getter)
  end
end
```

The way I see it, I just defined two methods, `obj.name` as getter and `obj.name=` as the setter. But when I execute the code in IRB and call `obj.name = "A string"` it still works, even though I defined the method without a space!

I know this is just part of the magic that defines Ruby, but what exactly makes this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the ruby interpreter sees `obj.name = "A string`, it will ignore the space between `name` and `=` and look for a method named `name=` on your `obj`.

Comment: Uh oh, that reading comprehension of mine, I seem to have answered wrong question :], +1 for ya.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, 'A string' is a perfectly good message name, just try

```
obj.send "A string" # ^_^
```

You can even use numbers:

```
o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method "555" do "kokot" end
o.send "555"
```

Comment: OK, I answered different question than you asked here :)